# How can we pass an object of an extended class between two activities in android?

Tags: android

```
public class forTesting extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements Serializable  {
    transient public String string="basant";

    public forTesting(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "abc.db", null, 1);
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}


public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        forTesting obj=(forTesting) intent.getSerializableExtra("object");
        Toast.makeText(this,obj.string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


    btndelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    forTesting object=new forTesting(MainActivity.this);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("object",object);
                    startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

Blockquote

> forTesting.java is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper which is implemented as Serializable.I create an object of forTesting.java class and pass it into an intent in MainActivity and try to get this object into NewActivity but i got an error.

```
>>Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.example.dbms.forTesting).
>>>I try a lot but till i am not able to resolve it .
>>>>please help me.
>>>>>Thank you!
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass `object` instead create new one in `NewActivity`

Comment: Actually my real code is different. I am working with DataBase  by using Sqlite Class.I create an object of DataBaseClassHelper.java which is extended by SQLiteOpenHelper.java in MainActivity but i required this object into another activity.Because my real code is lengthy so i give here only a sample of code.